# how does javascript currying function actually works?

Tags: javascript, function, currying

i've been having a lot of trouble understand how this currying function actually works
and what exactly its doing ?

```js
   Function.prototype.curry = function() {
   var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
   return function() {
     return fn.apply(this, args.concat(
       Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
   };
 };
```

because im only familiar with this type of currying function:

```js
function curry(f) { 
  return function(a) {
    return function(b) {
      return f(a, b);
    };
  }
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. What it is actually doing is [partial application, not currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application).

Comment: A more modern version of the first snippet (and using a function instead of a method) would be `(f, ...pargs) => (...args) => f(...pargs, ...args)`  whereas yours is `curry = (f) => (a) => (b) => f(a, b)`

Comment: @ceving Yes, it's unclear to me what particular trouble OP has to understand the function, and how much detail they expect from an explanation of "*what exactly its doing*". That's why I can't answer but only provide helpful (possibly insightful) comments.

Comment: @Bergi I think the comment of an answer is a good place to specify that.